# Autocomplete not working on cloned input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Autocomplete working perfect on first input element

```
<input type="text" id="inp01"></input>
```

but after making **clone** of this input autocomplete not working for new

```
<input type="text" id="inp02"></input>
autocm("inp02");
```

my autocomplete function is

```
function autocm(inputID){
  //tempdata have an array of strings
  $(document.body).find("#" + inputID).autocomplete({
        source: tempData
  });
};
```

Comment: This new element is created by dynamically?

Comment: yes this is created by .clone() method

Comment: then i think you should use delegate() for this its work fine

Comment: I want autocomplete to work on all input

Comment: You have tagged `angularJs` as well. Which autocomplete library you are using? Can you create [jsfiiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) example? Please update your question with information asked and we'll try to help you with possible answers.

Comment: Looks like, he is using jqueryUI library

Comment: If you want to for all then you need to add `class` instead of `id`

Comment: @Samundra i am using jquery ui autocomplete. and both input element have different id so why i do i have an class on input.

Comment: May be you need to bind autocomplete event to work on dynamically created elements.

Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8211263/6608101

Comment: @Loading.. i have already tried that solution but it stil filter values as per first input

Comment: Please see that answer that I have updated. You can `Run code snippet` attached and see the working example. Please let us know whether it worked for you or not.

Comment: After some digging i got the solution. we first need to remove autocomplete class from cloned element then again bind autocomplete. then this works fine. Anyway thanx guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging i found this solution.

1. Autocomplete add an class to a input element.
2. When we cloned input element then that class also present already.
3. so before initialise autocomplete to an cloned element we first need to remove that class "ui-autocomplete-input";
4. then call autocomplete function on that input.

Answer (score 1):

See the code snippet below, where I have used the jQuery UI along with jQuery UI autocomplete. The functionality works, Please ignore the missing style, you can easily fix it.

**How it works**:

At first, I cloned the input element and then rebind the autocomplete on it and then enable `autocomplete` on it. The snippet that you are interested is as follows:

```
    $(tag2).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    }).autocomplete('enable');
```

You can run and test the snippet. Please let us know whether it works for you or not.

Sample Run

1. Run the `Run code snippet`
2. Click on `Try clone and bind`. You will see input field with `clone-*` value by default. Here * will be incrementing numbers 2, 3, 4 etc.
3. Click on `clone-2` and try to change value to something starting with `a`, `b`. You will see autocomplete appearing on the fields.

Try to study the code and tweak it to your need. Let us know if you still feel confused on it.

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
  
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
    
    var count   = 1;
    var cloneId = 'clone-';
    
    $('#tryClone').on('click', function() {
        var tag2 = $('#tags').clone();
        tag2.removeAttr("id");
        
        count += 1;
      
        var elementId = cloneId + count;
   
        $(tag2).attr("id", elementId).val(elementId);
        
        $(tag2).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        }).autocomplete('enable');
        

        $(tag2).appendTo('#container');
    });
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
  
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  
  <button id="tryClone">
      Try clone and bind
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx @Samundra but this does't solve my problem. after some digging i got solution that first i need to remove autocomplete class from that element then again bind autocomplete.

Comment: That's great. You found solution. By the way, the autocomplete plugin should have removed the `autocomplete` class by itself when its `close` event gets fired.

Comment: No its not removed class. its just disable the autocomplete widget for that input element

Comment: I agree. When I tested the autocomplete, input element had extra attribute `autocomplete=off` for cloned input.