# Additional fields use the same JQuery Autocomplete script

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have an issue for a feature I'm creating. Basically I want the user to add their specialities to their profile. I have created a form and have got the page adding additional fields by clicking a button. See the JSFiddle code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wowdesignsolutions/X5Efu/6/

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="text-long" name="Title[]" id="Title1" rel="autocomp1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="SPSCode[]" id="SPSCode1" value="0" rel="autospcode1" />
    <br>
<span class="addafter" onclick="counterA++;counterB++;afterText()">Add another speciality</span>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var counterA = 0;
var counterB = 1;

function afterText() {
    var txt1 = '<input type="text" class="text-long-add" name="Title[]" id="Title' + counterB + '" rel="autocomp' + counterB + '" /><input type="hidden" name="SPSCode[]" id="SPSCode' + counterB + '" value="0" rel="autospcode' + counterB + '" />';
    $("input[id^='SPSCode" + counterA + "']").after(txt1);
}

$(function t() {
    var dentisttypes = [
        "Special Care Dentistry",
        "Oral Surgery",
        "Paediatric Dentistry",
        "Orthodontics",
        "Endodontics",
        "Periodontics",
        "Prosthodontics",
        "Restorative Dentistry",
        "Dental Public Health",
        "Oral Medicine",
        "Oral Microbiology",
        "Oral and Maxillofacial Pathology",
        "Dental and Maxillofacial Radiology",
        "Dental Anesthesiology",
        "Special Needs Dentistry",
        "Forensic Odontology",
        "Geriatric Dentistry"];
    $("input[rel^='autocomp']").autocomplete({
        type: "POST",
        source: dentisttypes,
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function (e, t) {
            $("input[rel='autocomp" + counterB + "']").val(t.item.label);
            $("input[rel='autospcode" + counterB + "']").val(t.item.value);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (e, t) {
            $("input[rel='autocomp" + counterB + "']").val(t.item.label);
            $("input[rel='autospcode" + counterB + "']").val(t.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    })
        .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (e, t) {
        return $("<li>").append("<a>" + t.label + "</a>").appendTo(e);
    };
});
```

The issue I'm having is getting the "autocomplete" to work on the new input fields that are created. I want ALL the new input fields, and the original one, to use the same autocomplete. The actual autocomplete list is produced from a database, but I've hard coded it in for the example.

Any ideas on how to activate the autocomplete on all the new rel="autocomp" input fields?

This answer is very close to what I want ([Autocomplete on appended field in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786117/autocomplete-on-appended-field-in-jquery)), but I'm not using lists and I already have code to create the new input fields. If I was to use the code in this answer, how do I tweak (such as what triggers the click event etc.)?

Cheers
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
var counterA = 0;
var counterB = 1;

function afterText() {
    var txt1 = '<input type="text" class="text-long-add" name="Title[]" id="Title' + counterB + '" rel="autocomp' + counterB + '" /><input type="hidden" name="SPSCode[]" id="SPSCode' + counterB + '" value="0" rel="autospcode' + counterB + '" />';
    $("input[id^='SPSCode" + counterA + "']").after(txt1);
    t();
}

function t() {
    var dentisttypes = [
        "Special Care Dentistry",
        "Oral Surgery",
        "Paediatric Dentistry",
        "Orthodontics",
        "Endodontics",
        "Periodontics",
        "Prosthodontics",
        "Restorative Dentistry",
        "Dental Public Health",
        "Oral Medicine",
        "Oral Microbiology",
        "Oral and Maxillofacial Pathology",
        "Dental and Maxillofacial Radiology",
        "Dental Anesthesiology",
        "Special Needs Dentistry",
        "Forensic Odontology",
        "Geriatric Dentistry"];
    $("input[rel^='autocomp']").autocomplete({
        type: "POST",
        source: dentisttypes,
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function (e, t) {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var selectedNum = id.charAt(id.length - 1);
            var hiddenId = "SPSCode" + selectedNum;
            $("#" + id).val(t.item.label);
            $("#" + hiddenId).val(t.item.value);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (e, t) {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var selectedNum = id.charAt(id.length - 1);
            var hiddenId = "SPSCode" + selectedNum;
            $("#" + id).val(t.item.label);
            $("#" + hiddenId).val(t.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    })
        .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (e, t) {
        return $("<li>").append("<a>" + t.label + "</a>").appendTo(e);
    };
}

t();
```

You might want to consider efficiency for many fields by adding a parameter to the function that takes in the object to which you want to add the autocomplete and only add the autocomplete to that object.

Comment: Hi @Moriaty. That worked great. I think I know what you mean by adding a parameter to the function. If you view the latest [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wowdesignsolutions/X5Efu/7/), with your code, and add multiple fields and THEN type into the boxes, the autocomplete adds the chosen field to the bottom field. Is there a way around this? Cheers G

Comment: @Moriaty Thanks, this is perfect! So grateful! Cheers G